# Formatting model.errors.full_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you format columns names in error messages?

```
class Person
  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :email
  validates_length_of :name, in: 5..30
end

person = Person.create(address: '123 First St.')
person.errors.full_messages
# => ["Name is too short (minimum is 5 characters)",   
"Name can't be blank", "Email can't be blank"]
```

For example, when there is an error instead I want it to print

Full name can't be blank. (instead of 'Name')

How do I do this since in the model/database its stored as :name.

Is there someway I can link a string to :name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can specify a custom message.**

```
validates_length_of :name, in: 5..30, message: 'Full name must be between 5 and 30 characters'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message

**You can also just translate the attribute**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      person:
        name: "Full name"
```

By adding that to the `config/locales/en.yml` file 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models